# angular location path not changing with keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*I want to hit the escape key anywhere on the page without focusing on any element like a button or input.* Why does this fail:

```
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      $location.path("/");
    }
  });
```

But this works?

```
  $scope.cancelEdit = function() {
      $location.path('/');
  }
```

HTML for the latter:

```
<button ng-click="cancelEdit()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

**1. Neither of these work:**

`$document.on('keyup', function(e) {.....`

`$document.bind('keyup', function(e) {....`

**2. Here is the full HTML:**

```
<div class="edit jumbotron">
  <i id="loader" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
  <form name="editForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveEdit()">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">Edit Site Actions</div>
        <table class="edit_table table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="action_name_cell">Action</th>
              <th class="float_cell">Warning Threshold</th>
              <th class="float_cell">Error Threshold</th>
              <th class="toggle_cell">Enabled</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="data_row" ng-repeat="row in get_edit_rows()">
              <td class="action_name_cell">{{row.action_name}}</td>
              <td class="float_cell">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="row.warning"
                         name="{{row.threshold_id}}_warning"
                         placeholder="10.0" ng-value="row.warning"
                         ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"
                         step="0.1" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="float_cell">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="row.error"
                         name="{{row.threshold_id}}_error"
                         placeholder="10.0" ng-value="row.error"
                         ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"
                         step="0.1" required />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="toggle_cell">
                <label></label>
                <toggle ng-model="row.enabled" name="{{row.threshold_id}}_enabled"
                        ng-true-value="'on'" ng-false-value="'off'"></toggle>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- END panel / panel-info -->

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div class="base_button_wrapper">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      <button ng-click="cancelEdit()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is placed your first script ?

Comment: in a controller

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that jQuery selector can't work in an AngularJS Controller method

Comment: Why do you write it in a controlller? It s a jquery bind eve t and should be in somewhere in root. I think this is the peoblem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    $location.path("/");
  }
});
```

Use `$document` service :

```
$document.bind('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $location.path("/");
    });
  }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vxtktonz/)**

NOTE: Don't forget to remove your event with `$document.unbind('keyup')` in `$scope.$on('$destroy', ...);` to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Is it angularish way of document?

Comment: And any idea why jQuery binding does not work in controller?

Comment: Because the jQuery listener is not in the AngularJS' stack. If you REALLY want to execute the code, you should wrap it in a `$timeout` call. But I won't recommend it.

Comment: The code I wrote does not require jQuery since AngularJS has already jqLite.

Comment: I included $document in both my controller and controller function params but I see "$document.on is not a function" logged

Comment: Try `bind` instead of `on`.

Comment: This is probably due to your angular version. `bind` is now deprecated and we should use `on`.

Comment: Both throw the same "X... not a function" console error. I'm using version 1.6.5

Comment: I edited my post. You can find a working fiddle. I found out that jqLite listener is not in the AngularJS' stack (?!). You have to wrap it in a `$timeout` to get it working.

Comment: I have no idea why I can't get `$document.on` to work but using `var $ = angular.element; $('body')` and the rest of your code works great. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can handle key events on the elementes like this

```
add this directive to the element

ng-keyup="cancelEditEscape($event)"
$scope.cancelEditEscape = function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
          $location.path("/");
        }
};
```

for example:

```
<div ng-keyup="cancelEditEscape($event)">
     <!-- another html stuff -->
     <button ng-click="cancelEdit()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Here is a plnkr with an [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/drVv2uzywuwbEi0WjG5E/)

**update**
for your html you could put `<div class="edit jumbotron" ng-keyup="cancelEditEscape($event)">`
or in the `<form ng-keyup="cancelEditEscape($event)">`

Comment: What if there is no element, and I want the key event to work regardless of which element has focus?

Comment: put on the parent element of the button. or in the <body>. by the way the parent must be in the ambit of your controller.

Comment: I've put the directive on all large elements in my view which is under my controller, but it never fires the event when I log it. This only seems to work for an input or button, etc.

Comment: i update answer check the plnkr , try press esc and check console browser. you must see exit string

Comment: lol not... if you check the consoloe it will count the times.  (1)exit , (2)exit. the console browser not put new line. if is from the same line of code.

Comment: also obvius the focus must be in the element or child elementes who has the directive and controller ambit..

Comment: it doesn't put any line in the console until you click the input

Comment: could you provide you entire html to know how you need to implement.

Comment: still only works AFTER you click on an input or button element

Comment: if you want to handle on th entire html i think you need https://github.com/rafaelcamargo/ng-surprise... to handle on every you want element. tryout.

Comment: i still remain obvius need to be focused an element or child element, for other intances need more sophisticated solution like i mention above (https://github.com/rafaelcamargo/ng-surprise)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because you are mixing jQuery and angular (and the jQuery event not being part of the angular scope). It seems you are still using angular 1.x so I bet ngKeyUp will work: [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup).

example (not tested):

```
<button ng-keyup="cancelEdit()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: to which element do you assign the ngKeyUp event if you want it to affect the entire page?

Comment: I want it to work on the entire page. So no matter where the focus is, escape triggers the location change. This only works while focusing on the button itself.

Comment: This is an example you can set the ng-keyup on a different element

Comment: Seems to only work for button, input ,etc. not div, body, html, etc.